# How to wire up a ClaimsAuthenticationManager in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)?

Tags: wif, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 4 (vCurrent), you can wire up a `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` for claims transformation in the `<system.identityModel>` configuration section:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
        <claimsAuthenticationManager type="Security.CustomClaimsAuthenticationManager, Security" />
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

Where can I wire this up in the new version -- ASP.NET 5 (vNext)? I saw this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/213) in the `Identity` repository on GitHub. It's kind of vague, so I'm not sure if it's related. Perhaps this is simply not yet implemented or the approach has changed?

Thanks, Pete